# Importing jsPDF modules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

First, allow me to apologize if this question has an obvious solution or exists elsewhere. I am a JavaScript newcomer and so don't have the requisite vocabulary established yet.

I'm trying to use the [jsPdf](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) library to construct a PDF programmatically. So far, things have worked pretty well. I installed the module using `npm install jspdf --save` and the import of the main library works without any problems:

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

export function ConvertToPdf(data) {

    const doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'portrait',
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'a4',
    });

    doc.save('test');
}
```

However, I'm trying to use the `splitTextToSize`, [documented here](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-split_text_to_size.html), function to wrap some text but I can't seem to import it. I've tried a variety of combinations to import the module it's in:

```
import split_text_to_size;
import split_text_to_size.js;
import modules/split_text_to_size;
import modules/split_text_to_size.js;
import jspdft/modules/split_text_to_size;
```

I'm not sure if it's just not installed or the import path is different than what appears to be the case in the documentation. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.